# Question tag for "you must have felt it too"?

Tags: modal-verbs, question-tags, perfect-infinitive

Which of these question tags is most appropriate for

> There has been an earthquake. You must have felt it too, __ ?

1. – , haven't you?
2. – , didn't you?
3. – , mustn't you?

Comment: Without context, I would advise not to use any of those. You could say: "You must have felt it too, correct?" or "You must have felt it too, right?" (Second is very informal but common.) You have quite a high StackExchange score, so maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: ', no?' works in all cases. If the feeling was a single instance, ', didn't you?' works. If the feeling is habitual, ',haven't you?' works.

Comment: But if this is purely technical, the direct negative question tag would be "mustn't."

Comment: @ChristopherIssac: it could have been "It must have been terrible.", referring to someone losing a parent, for instance. If I want to use a question tag, should it be ", mustn't it?", ", wasn't it?", or "hasn't it"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I was thinking of something like an earthquake.

Comment: -mustn't you? Doesn't work in this context. I'd go for "You must have felt that earthquake, surely?" But that doesn't answer your question, does it? :)

Comment: I think this is probably a bad question from a poor textbook. -- If you want the mark, use "mustn't you". When you actually write or use such a construction, the responses given in the comments and answer are idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

First, the terminology. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question) deems tacked-on questions other than those mirroring the grammar of the statement (eg ", yes?") to also qualify as tag questions.

Second, what questions can be tagged onto "You must have felt it too"?

Certainly the suggestions given not containing a verb (", correct?" / ", right?" / ", yes?" / ", no?") and recasts (" ... you did, didn't you?") are all quite acceptable.

"haven't you" doesn't work with a single event (an earthquake). It would work here: "There have been several smallish earthquakes this month. You must have felt them too, haven't you?" [", didn't you?" also works here]

"didn't you?" *does* work here: "I was woken by quite a pronounced tremor last night. You must have felt it too ... didn't you?" [the pause disguises a certain awkwardness resulting from the verb switch]

But "mustn't you" would only be used in a situation like this to persuade someone of what seems inescapable but which they're unsure about, rather than purely to check on facts:

"You must have left it at Auntie Jane's, mustn't you?" [two levels: solicitous or browbeating]

(ie "you've got to agree that it's what actually happened". The 'must' in "You must have felt it too" holds far less conviction; the tag question is proof of that. So ", mustn't you?" is unavailable after "You must have felt it too" here as it defaults to a different sense.)

Comment: I don't know if there's a specific term for this kind of transformation but, as I understand it (albeit mostly intuitively), *You must have felt it too* is the result of applying this unidentified transformation to either *You felt it too* or *You have felt it too*. That explains to me why *didn't you* would work better in some cases and *haven't you* in others.